# Does endianness reverse an array?

Tags: c, network-programming, endianness

I am receiving a buffer from the network, which is big endian, and I'm on a little endian system. Do I have to reverse the buffer before using it on my system? I'm not sure if the endianness only reverses the byte ordering for a single type or if it also applies to an entire buffer.

For instance, let's say I'm receiving a buffer of `unsigned long`s from the network, and I'm on a little endian system. The code would be this:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    system_buffer[i]=ntohl(network_buffer[i]);
```

Before I use system_buffer, do I also have to reverse it (so the last element becomes the first element and visa versa)?

```
reverse_buffer(system_buffer);
```

Furthermore, if I'm receiving an array of `unsigned char`s, do I need to compensate for endianness at all, or can I use the buffer as-is?

Thanks!

Comment: Read this:http://commandcenter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endianess is only applicable to single variables,
ie. only to each array element value, not to the order of elements in the array.

And 1-byte-variables can´t have their byte order reversed,
so no need to do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

Endianness affects the byte order of integers of size larger than one byte only (i.e. it does not affect a byte or `int8_t`).

You need to read the protocol description in what byte order the integers are.

Answer (score 1):

Endianness only affects the order of bytes (not bits) in a data word. Since a `char` is always one-byte in size, you don't have to do any adjustments to them. The standard library function `ntohl` changes the byte order of an unsigned integer (`l`) from network byte order (`n`) to host byte order (`h`). Therefore you don't need to reverse the buffer before using it. You only need to change the byte order of each element in the buffer.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // network byte order to system byte order

    system_buffer[i] = ntohl(network_buffer[i]);
}

// process system_buffer
```